# New field under Azure DevOps (VSTS/TFS) iteration capacity tab

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops, capacity

I am looking for a method to customize the capacity tab to include new field for each team member where i can specify the buffer time for each one during the sprint.

Is it possible to add such new field entry under capacity tab or not?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible right now. You can help upvote this to increase visibility of this need to the product team in developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365553/vsts-custom-team-capacity-activity-as-well-as-cust.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)