# How can I change the value of the predefined fields?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am trying to change the options listed in ****Requirement Typ field** in the **Work item type - Feature**.

The witadmin gives me the properties of the field as follows@

```
  Field: Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RequirementType
  Name: Requirement Type
  Type: String
  Indexed: False
  Reportable As: dimension
  Synchronizes Identity Name Changes: False
```

1. Is it possible to add or modify the listed values of this field ?
2. if possible, how do i do that please?

Eg: Functional is one of the value in the list and I would like to add Non-Functional, Security and Access etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New field under Azure DevOps (VSTS/TFS) iteration capacity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362944/new-field-under-azure-devops-vsts-tfs-iteration-capacity-tab)